# Rapid and extreme oxidation of steel in chemical cabinet

Tags: rust, chemicals

I have a storage cabinet for flammable chemicals and products, think gas can, spray paint cans, brake clean, mineral spirits, etc. I've noticed that containers with exposed steel (e.g., spray cans, paint cans) are aggressively oxidizing (rusting). "something" in the cabinet is off-gassing or releasing vapors that are reacting with the steel. The cabinet itself seems fine, but it's fully painted so not surprising. Nothing is visibly leaking, I don't have puddles of chemicals in the cabinet. The issue is affecting all areas of the cabinet, i.e., not limited to one shelf or corner.

This oxidation ONLY happens in the cabinet. I have other cans and containers (non-flammable) outside the cabinet and they have zero visible oxidation.

Also, before anyone says it: Yes, I know there are non-flammable items in the cabinets; I also use it to organize my stuff so I know where to find, say, my various lubricants.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? If so, did you determine the culprit?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: One or more containers with loose caps/lids/non-air tight might off gas enough in a closed cabinet.  There is enough chemicals in there to make nasty stuff.

Comment: Such cabinets typically have a 1.5-2" pipe threaded ventilation port or three. Try connecting that to a pipe leading outside. Standard culprit would be acids. Looks like an open, mostly empty vinegar bottle laying in the bottom, for instance.

Comment: Bleach is another common culprit. The fumes from either acids or bleach will cause rusting of exposed steel.

Comment: Does it get wet in there?  We had a container with a leak and all the cans did that.  They were $200/gallon paint cans, so I media blasted the cans and painted them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Good eye on the vinegar, however they're 100% empty and cleaned out. I use for mixing 2-stroke gas and other similar tasks.

Comment: To all - no moisture (hygrometer is in the 50% range) and no bleaches. I did have muriatic acid and it was leaking, so I think that was the culprit. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Rust is caused by oxidation, so look to see if you either have something causing the cabinet to be extra humid, or if any of the chemicals are oxidizing agents.  Common such are oxygen, hydrogen peroxide, nitric acid, sodium hypochlorite (bleach).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A plastic jug of muriatic acid in the cabinet will rust any exposed steel in the vicinity due to offgassing of hydrogen chloride gas. If you transfer the acid to a glass jug with a bakelite cap, it will stop offgassing, since glass is impermeable to HCl.

I keep my glass jug of muriatic acid in a plastic tote containing a few pounds of pelletized lime (the lawn and garden variety) so if some disaster causes the jug to break, the lime will neutralize the acid and help prevent further spread of the acid. Marble chips would work too, but not as quickly.

Comment: I had to look that up… & I was a chemistry major at school. I'd never heard of muriatic acid until now. To me it's always just been hydrochloric. Why on earth would anyone keep open containers of HCl in a cupboard?

Comment: @Tetsujin Not open containers but a closed, sealed plastic jug. The HCl gas molecule migrates right through the plastic. (Based on past experience, I think it's the PE jugs that do this, not the PVC jugs.) On this side of the pond it's called hydrochloric acid in chem lab and industry but the common name for retail consumers is muriatic acid. From Latin *muria*, brine. Electrolyze brine to make hydrogen on one electrode, chlorine on the other; react the gases to make HCl gas. The liquid left behind is aqueous NaOH. Guess who else was a chem major?!?

Comment: @Tetsujin That was me too, the first time I heard "muriatic".

Comment: I checked today and not only found muriatic/hydrochloric acid, but it was leaking a small amount. I'm pretty confident that was the culprit. I removed it and placed a non-oxidized can in the cabinet to see what happens. Thank you @MTA for the answer.

Comment: @SteveK Be aware that there may be residual HCl gas absorbed into paper or cardboard in the cabinet, or even lurking as a gas under spray can caps. You can neutralize it by taking a folded paper towel, placing it in a saucer and wetting it with household ammonia solution. Close the doors. The ammonia gas will diffuse into all the nooks and crannies and neutralize the HCl gas. Don't be concerned if it creates a white fog. That's harmless ammonium chloride, a solid "fume" in air that will soon settle.

Comment: @MTA - Noted, I appreciate the follow up and suggestion. Happy New Year!